# After Drupal bootstrap, PHP echo outputs nothing

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a PHP script that is invoked from the command line. It taps into Drupal:

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = "127.0.0.1";
$_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] = "Dummy";
$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] = "";
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once('./includes/bootstrap.inc');
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

After the drupal_bootstrap() line, echo doesn't output anything. A few Drupal versions ago it did. Also, if I run a command line program using passthru(), it doesn't output anything, either. It's as if stdout/stderr handles have been closed or redirected away.

Any idea if that's indeed the case, and if it's a setting in Drupal that I can flip back?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your script does, you could leverages `scripts/drupal.sh` to mock an http request to Drupal (so you're custom code would likely live in a menu hook) or (better yet) port the custom code so it can be executed via [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush).

Comment: Using scripts/drupal.sh is the newer way to create command line scripts and takes care of setting up the environment for you (like populating `$_SERVER`. Drush is an even more better way to interact with Drupal on the command line.

Comment: I'm not after executing Drupal Web pages. I have a command line PHP script that does many Drupal-unrelated things, but then needs to update a Drupal node.